# Game Center order change

Tags: ios, xcode, game-center

I have a problem with my Game Center configuration. I just released the game and all my game center leaderboards are ordered in the wrong way. The should be Descending but they are Ascending. The app is live in the AppStore.

Does anyone know how can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Sign into iTunes Connect, select your app, select Game Center, then in the Leaderboards section, select your existing Leaderboard to edit it.

Now find the "Sort Order" setting, and switch it from "Low to High" to "High to Low" and save.

When you're creating a Leaderboard, you can set the Sort Order there as well, in the same way.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Yeap. The problem is that you cannot do that ones the app is living on the appStore.

Comment: is there a solution to change the sort order when your app is live?

Comment: Having the same problem. Anyone know if there is a way of changing sort order once app is live... otherwise my app is dead :-(